# How can I quickly load large amounts of data in a ListView and then filter it with a SearchView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, searchview

I'm new with Android and I'm looking for the best way to load a large amount of data in a ListView and then filter them with SearchView.
I get the data from a database with a query that returns approximately 25000 records.
This is the solution that I was able to implement, but not sure it's the best (certainly is not the fastest!):

This is the fragment:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

ListView lv;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
SearchView sv;
ArrayList<MyObject> listMyObject;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sv = (SearchView) getView().findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    setData("");

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            setData(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void setData(String params) {
    String query = "select *, count(*) as num from table where field_1 like '" + params + "%' group by field_1 order by field_1";
    listMyObject= new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    String ... ;
    int ...;


    dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ...
                listMyObject.add(new MyObject(...));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    arrayAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_row, listMyObject);
    lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

as this solution is a bit 'slow (having a lot of data), how can I do to speed up the loading of the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check available SQLite/ ORM libraries b'z they have implemented lots of feature like caching db or reactive db etc. and choose as per your requirement. and then try load data using paging in sql queries.

Check this [List of libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/25)